# Blender doesnt report opencl devices

Tags: opencl

I have two GPUs on my system, a nVidia GTX 1650 and a AMD 5700XT. Blender reports CUDA support for the nvidia card, but it doesnt report openCL support for the AMD card nor the nVidia card.

[image]

`clinfo` shows that I have OpenCL support for both cards. This is the part for the AMD card.

```
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (NAVI10, DRM 3.36.0, 5.6.10-arch1-1, LLVM 10.0.0)
  Device Vendor                                   AMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 20.0.6
  Driver Version                                  20.0.6
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Max compute units                               40
  Max clock frequency                             2030MHz
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
=== CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ===
fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/lib/clc/gfx1010-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory
  Preferred work group size multiple              <getWGsizes:1200: create kernel : error -46>
  Preferred / native vector sizes
    char                                                16 / 16
    short                                                8 / 8
    int                                                  4 / 4
    long                                                 2 / 2
    half                                                 8 / 8        (cl_khr_fp16)
    float                                                4 / 4
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (cl_khr_fp16)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              8589934592 (8GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           6871947673 (6.4GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       32768 bits (4096 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   No
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     16
  Max constant buffer size                        2147483647 (2GiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      0ns
  Execution capabilities
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_fp16
```

Is there something I have to do to enable opencl support with the AMD card?